# UIImage to another UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, uiimageview

In my project, I have two `UIViewControllers`. On my first ViewController, I have a `UIImageView` and there is an image from an `url`. On the second ViewController, I have an empty `UIImageView`.

When the user clicks on the image in the `UIImageView` on the first `ViewController`, the image in the second `ViewController` (which was empty before) should be the same like the clicked one on the first `ViewController`.

Is something like that possible? The image is from a `url` (like I wrote before), so i think it should work, but I have no idea how I can do that.

Comment: you can pass that url of the image to second view controller when you are showing that  viewController

Comment: the image changes, it stands for "your last activity" so I think thats not possible

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't get you

Comment: you can create a custom delegate

Comment: you can set property when navigate to secondviewcontroller.

Comment: but then its like a button, and I don't want a button

Comment: so you how to navigate to secondviewcontroller?

Comment: via tabbar,  I want to display the image from the first VC in an ImageView in the second VC. And when I click on the first VC on an other image, the ImageView on the second VC should change too

Comment: @j10 You just need to pass url of image to second view controller after click of image from firstviewcontroller and then when you switch the tab you need to set that image from url to uiimageview in viewDidLoad method

Comment: @Ashok Londhe, thx! do you have an example? I'm trying the whole day but I don't get it...

Comment: @j10 Wait i will post the answer

Comment: @Ashok Londhe, Thank you!

Comment: @j10 Welcome. Please check my answer. if its solve then good if not you can Skype me in night i will help you. skypeid : ashok londhe.1

Comment: @Ashok Londhe, I will try it and give you feedback later.

Comment: @j10 Sure go ahead.

Comment: @Ashok Londhe, It does not work yet. I have to go. Can you help me tomorrow? I will contact you between 9:00am and 11:00am CET.

Comment: Okay. wait for minute. i will update my answer. just 1 min.

Comment: Obvious answer - yes you can. Obvious question - what's the *relationship between the two view controllers? Are you segueing between VC1 and VC2? Or what?

Comment: @j10 i have updated my answer. please check.

Comment: @dfd, there is no relationship between the view controllers, they are different. Like I wrote in my question and comments, I have images on my first VC, and when the user clicks on one of these images, I want to display it on the second VC as "last activity". Do you understand me?

Comment: @Ashok Londhe, I will check tomorrow. Thanks in advance, I let you know tomorrow if it works!

Comment: @j10 try mine too..

Comment: @j10 Okay. Done

Comment: Yes, I understand. But part of my question was *how* you have the program flow move from VC1 to VC2. Segues are very simple, other ways a bit less so. Specifically, how are each VC instantiated, and how long are you retaining each instance?

Comment: @j10 are you loaded another view controller in contentView?

Answer (score 0):

Create a static property of `UIImage` in `firstVC`

```
static var imageFromUrl = UIImage()
```

Get image from url & assign it into `imageFromUrl`.

Now you can use in all ViewControllers simply calling by

```
FirstVC.imageFromUrl
```

Comment: how can i assign a `String` to a `UIImage`?

Comment: where you getting string?Do you have image in local or trying to get from url?

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow below steps :**  Swift

1) **Create var in appDelegate** :

```
var imageUrl = ""
```

**2) Create instance of appDelegate and set the url after click on image from firstView controller:  On click of UIImage From firstViewController....**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
appDelegate.imageUrl = self.imageUrl
```

**3) In `ViewDidLoad()` write code**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let url = URL(string: appDelegate.imageUrl)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
  let image = UIImage(data: data)
  myImageView.image =  image
}
```

**Or**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
backgroundImageView.downloadedFrom(link : appDelegate.imageUrl )
```

Comment: It does not work, I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` at `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: @j10 : Can you send me code which you used to set first image same code you need to use in second viewcontroller. update your question with code. Have you checked what appDelegate.imageUrl . please check it

Comment: @j10 Where you written my suggested answer i want to see all three files. Can please update it agian

Comment: @j10 where is the code to let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
appDelegate.imageUrl = self.imageUrl You didn't set imageUrl value

Comment: @j10 Please change this line cell.imageView.downloadedFrom(link :"mylink\(url)_W458.JPG") ... let imageUrl =  "mylink\(url)_W458.JPG" and cell.imageView.downloadedFrom(imageUrl). and set this imageUrl to appDelegate.imageUrl

Comment: Are you getting proper value of url in self.imageUrl please check and send me.

Comment: j10 I have updated my answer. Please check and check if your getting proper url in self.imageUrl or not.

Comment: it does not work, now the `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate appDelegate?.imageUrl = self.imageUrl` in second VC does not work

Comment: Write code in secondViewController : let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
backgroundImageView.downloadedFrom(link : appDelegate.imageUrl )

Comment: Please please check you are getting imageUrl or not do that in first priority

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCommunity = (liveCommunities?[indexPath.row].communityId)!
        let home = HomeViewController()
        home.showCommunityDetail()

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        appDelegate.imageUrl = self.imageUrl

    } Check here what is the value of self.imageUrl print it and check its proper url or not.

Comment: i get imageURL, thats not the problem

Comment: Write code in secondViewController : let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate backgroundImageView.downloadedFrom(link : appDelegate.imageUrl )

Comment: Do you have Skype id?

Comment: do you have a slack acc, thats better for the code fromatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148372/discussion-between-ashok-londhe-and-j10).

Comment: my skype id : ashok.londhe1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are trying to show the second view controller, so in you FirstViewController you can have:

1) if you are using storyboard segue you can use the prepare for segue :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {

        vc.imageView.image = self.imageView.image
    }
}
```

2) if you have some function the show the second view controller :

```
func presentSecondViewController() {

    let secondVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    secondVC.imageView.image = self.imageView.image
    present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And there are more ways but I guess you get the idea